# Password form in PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt

I made a login form but I don't know how to put ****** in the Password field. I only have:

```
self.textPass = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
```

Comment: try: `self.textPass.setEchoMode(QtGui.QLineEdit.Password)`

Answer (score 32, accepted):

As jedwards commented, use [`setEchoMode` method](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qlineedit.html#setEchoMode):

example:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

app = QtGui.QApplication([])
pw = QtGui.QLineEdit()
pw.setEchoMode(QtGui.QLineEdit.Password)
pw.show()
app.exec_()
```

See also [`QLineEdit.EchoMode` enum](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qlineedit.html#EchoMode-enum).

Answer (score 8):

In PyQt5:

```
self.LeUsuario.setEchoMode(QtWidgets.QLineEdit.Password)
```

Comment: This is a very good standalone example. It works without needing qtwidgets, which saves drive space.

Answer (score 1):

**PyQT5 solution with option to hide/reveal typed content**

Install:

```
pip install qtwidgets
```

Then you can use:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from qtwidgets import PasswordEdit


class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        password = PasswordEdit()
        self.setCentralWidget(password)


app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
w = Window()
w.show()
app.exec_()
```

[Taken from](https://www.learnpyqt.com/widgets/passwordedit/)

**Another solution (for **PyQT5**):**

```
password = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
password.setEchoMode(QLineEdit.Password)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add the following line

```
self.textPass.setEchoMode(QtWidgets.QLineEdit.Password)
```

Answer (score 0):

In PyQt6:

```
entry_passsword = QLineEdit()
entry_passsword.setEchoMode(QLineEdit.EchoMode.Password)
```